Backtrader plotting returns NaN or Inf error
I m starting out with backtrader. I can load data into the object but plotting fails with a strange error message.
I can create an object with sample data, like so:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import backtrader as bt
from datetime import datetime

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', end='2023-12-31', freq='B')
np.random.seed(42)  
df_random = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df_random['High'] = np.random.uniform(low=100, high=200, size=(len(date_rng)))
df_random['Low'] = np.random.uniform(low=50, high=100, size=(len(date_rng)))
df_random['Open'] = np.random.uniform(low=75, high=150, size=(len(date_rng)))
df_random['Close'] = np.random.uniform(low=75, high=150, size=(len(date_rng)))
df_random.set_index('date', inplace=True)


cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.adddata(MyDataFeed(dataname=df_random))
cerebro.addstrategy(St)
cerebro.run()

with the custom loader like this:
class MyDataFeed(bt.feeds.PandasData):  
    params = (  
        ('datetime', None),  
        ('high', -1),  
        ('low', -1),  
        ('open', -1),  
        ('close', -1),  
        ('volume', None),
        ('openinterest', None),
    )

and this super basic strategy:
class St(bt.Strategy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sma = bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(self.data)

As said, it seems to load the data correctly. But
cerebro.plot(iplot=False) 

returns the error:

ValueError: Axis limits cannot be NaN or Inf

However there is no NaN in my dataframe.

Looks like backtrader expects volume
check updated code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import backtrader as bt


class MyDataFeed(bt.feeds.PandasData):
    params = (
        ("datetime", None),
        ("high", -1),
        ("low", -1),
        ("open", -1),
        ("close", -1),
        ("volume", -1),
        ("openinterest", None),
    )


class St(bt.Strategy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sma = bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(self.data)


date_rng = pd.date_range(start="2023-01-01", end="2023-12-31", freq="B")
np.random.seed(42)
df_random = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=["date"])
df_random["High"] = np.random.uniform(low=100, high=200, size=(len(date_rng)))
df_random["Low"] = np.random.uniform(low=50, high=100, size=(len(date_rng)))
df_random["Open"] = np.random.uniform(low=75, high=150, size=(len(date_rng)))
df_random["Close"] = np.random.uniform(low=75, high=150, size=(len(date_rng)))
df_random["Volume"] = np.random.randint(low=1000, high=10000, size=(len(date_rng)))
df_random.set_index("date", inplace=True)


cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.adddata(MyDataFeed(dataname=df_random))
cerebro.addstrategy(St)
cerebro.run()
cerebro.plot(iplot=False)


